# How to return from loop when condition satisfied in angular?

Tags: angular, foreach, rxjs, observable

I was calling this function from my routing.module.ts. This function checks if user has claim, return true else redirect him to error page.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: NavigationURL_EmployeeAuditChildren.PayItems, component: PayItemsComponent, canActivate: [EmployeeGuard], data: { claim: claims.employeePayItemAccess} }
}
```

For here this is called

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

        const claim: string = route.data[RouteData.Claim];

        return this.securityService.hasClaim(claim).pipe(
            map((hasClaim) => {
                if (hasClaim) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/forbidden']);
                    return false;
                }
            })
        );
    }
```

I need to modify this function, to check for multiple claims. If user has any of these claims, it should return true, else return error page. I'm thinking of using claims.map() to loop over each claim. But, how to return from inside it if any claim is found, else return error page?

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: NavigationURL_EmployeeAuditChildren.PayItems, component: PayItemsComponent, canActivate: [EmployeeGuard], data: { darwinClaim: [claims.employeePayItemAccess, claims.employeePayItemAuditAccess] } 
}
```

It Calls:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

        const claims: string[] = route.data[RouteData.Claim];

        claims.foreach(claim -> {
            this.securityService.hasClaim(claim).pipe(
                map((hasClaim) => {
                    if (hasClaim) {
                         return true;
                    }
                })
        )});
         this.router.navigate(['/forbidden']);
         return false;
    }
```

Comment: i'm using securityService.hasClaim() method to check I've claim. I'm doing other things inside it so can't remove it. It returns an observable. Now I've to run call this method inside a loop, but as it is observable, it makes things a lot difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const hasClaimsResult = forkJoin(claims.map(claim => this.securityService.hasClaim(claim)));

return hasClaimsResult.pipe(
    map(claims => {
        if (claims.every(claim => claim)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/forbidden']);
            return false;
        }
    })
);
```

Using map on the claims array will produce an `Array<Observable<boolean>>`, so I use `forkJoin` to transform it into an `Observable<Array<boolean>>`. Then we can pipe the resulting observable as we're used to and check that every value is true.